# Poner una imagen (svg) detrás de texto

Tags: html, css, svg

Estoy trabajando en la decoración de unos textos, y entre estos tengo que poner unos pocos gráficos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema radica en que no he podido poner uno de esos gráficos detrás del texto, intente con z-index, pero no me funciona y no se con que mas probar.

A continuación dejo el código

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.container__text {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  text-indent: 5.5rem;
}

.decorations {
  z-index: 1;
}

.container__text .text {
  z-index: 3;
}

.container__text .text p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}


/* Palabra de nivel 1 de importancia */

.pn1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* Palabra de nivel 2 de importancia */

.pn2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.pn1_1 {
  background-image: url("../img/linea3.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: 0 12px;
}

.container__text .decorations img {
  position: absolute;
}

.container__text .decorations .linea1 {
  right: 53%;
  top: 4%;
}

.container__text .decorations .linea2 {
  right: 15%;
  top: 13%;
}

.container__text .decorations .linea3 {
  width: 60%;
  right: 27%;
  top: 51%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style/style.css" />
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <head></head>
  <main>
    <div class="container__text">
      <div class="text">
        <p>
          Actividades <br />
          <span class="pn1">disruptivas,</span> <br />
          <span class="pn2">dinámicas y versátiles</span> <br /> que <span class="pn2">garantizan</span> <br />
          <span class="pn1 grafico">
              el aprendizaje
            </span> del <br />
          <span class="pn2">colaborador,</span> basados en <br />
          <span class="pn1">PNL, neuroseguridad</span> <br /> y el <span class="pn2"> insigt</span> IDEA
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="decorations">
        <img class="linea1" src="https://6rhvsb.csb.app/assets/img/linea1.svg" alt="" />
        <img class="linea2" src="https://6rhvsb.csb.app/assets/img/linea2.svg" alt="" />
        <img class="linea3" src="https://6rhvsb.csb.app/assets/img/linea3.svg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Agradezco sus comentarios positivos y ayuda.

Comment: se puede poner atras del texto, el tema es que vos tenes una sola caja y ahi adentro tenes texto e imagenes, sueltos.  Lo que yo haria, es una caja con fondo negro para el z-index 1, otra caja para los graficos con z-index 2, y finalmente otra para texto con z-index 3. Asi como lo tenes, el texto y su color de fondo siempre van a estar a la misma altura, y de esa manera nunca vas a ver el grafico por detras. Solo lo vas a ver cuando le pongas un z-index que lo traiga al frente.

Comment: Hola y que tal si el problema no esta competentemente en el código?
una solucion que te puedo dar ya que he trabajado con diseñadores ui es que exportes todos los gráficos como una sola imagen puede ser PNG o JPG y lo pones en CSS con la propiedad background

Comment: Hola, intente seguir tu consejo tal cual lo mencionas, pero aun así no funciona, de todas maneras gracias por tu comentario de ayuda.
Si quieres seguir ayudándome, nuevamente dejo el código editado con el mismo link: https://codesandbox.io/s/decorando-textos-6rhvsb?file=/index.html:789-1236